# Principal ideal domain question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and let $ I\neq \{0\} $ be a proper ideal.
Prove that $R/I$ is a field iff it is a integral domain.
if $R/I$ is a field then it is an integral domain by Def'$N$.

If $R/I$ is an integral domain then $I$ is a prime ideal. by theorem.

$I=\langle b \rangle $ for some $ b\in R $ since R is a principal ideal domain.

let $ a\in R $

WTS $ \exists r\in R $ such that $(a+I)(r+I)=(ar+I)=(1+I)$ or $(ar-1) \in I$

I believe i know that $R$ is an integral domain from the Def'$N$ that $R$ is a principal ideal domain. 
not really sure where to go from here but i think i have most of the pieces? i need something more before i can use the fact that $R$ is a principal ideal domain...

EDIT: We show that $I$ is maximal in the following way.

$I \subset J$ where $J= \langle c \rangle $ thus $ b \in \langle c \rangle $, so  b=ck for some $ k \in R $.

But ⟨b⟩ is a prime ideal.

So either c or k are in I if c is in I we are done as $I=J$ in this case so assume that c isn't in I so thus $k \in I$. thus k=bl for some l so b=cbl or $b(cl−1)=0$ but b≠0 by Def'n so $cl−1=0$ or $cl=1$ but since $ \exists l \in R $ s.t $cl=1 $ c is a unit so $J=R $ and thus I is maximal ideal.

Thus by theorem $<b> $ is maximal is equivalnt to $ R/<b> $ is a field hence if R/I is a integral domain and $I\neq \{0\} $ R/I is a field as desired.

Comment: Suppose $I$ is not a maximal ideal, i.e. it is contained in a proper ideal $J = \langle c \rangle$.  Think about the multiples of $c$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: do i want a=ck or c=ak? sorry im going super dyslexic on this question for some reason...

Comment: $b \in \langle c \rangle$, so you'll have $b = ck$ for some $k \in R$.  But $\langle b \rangle$ is a prime ideal...

Comment: so eithier c or k are in I if c is in I we are done as $ I=J$ so assume that c isnt in I so k must be in I. thus $k=bl$ for some $l$ so $b=cbl $ or $b(cl-1) =0 $ but $b \neq 0 $ so $ cl-1 =0 $ or $cl=1 $

Comment: i think this implys that c is a unit but im not really sure why?

Comment: Because there exists $l \in R$ such that $cl=1$.  That's literally the definition of a unit in a commutative unital ring.

Comment: omg! thank you its clear as mud now. your welcome to post your hint as an answer and ill accept.

Comment: No it's all good, you basically figured it out yourself with a couple of hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question basically boils down to show that in a PID $R$, every non-zero prime ideal is maximal.

So let's prove it. Take $P$ a non-zero prime ideal of $R$ and suppose for sake of contradiction that $P$ isn't maximal, then by Krull's theorem there is a maximal ideal $M$ of $R$ such that $P\subset M$. By hypothesis there are $p,m\in R$ such that $P=(p)$ and $M=(m)$. Then $p\in (p)\subset (m)$ implies that $p=mr$ for some $r\in R$. So $mr\in (p)=P$, which is a prime ideal, so by definition $m\in P$ or $r\in P$.

If $m\in P$, then $(m)=M\subset P$, so $P=M$, contradiction. Therefore it must be $r\in P$. This means that $r\in (p)$ which implies that there is some $s\in R$ such that $r=sp$. Hence we have $p=mr=msp$, so $p(1-ms)=0$. Now, as $p\neq 0$, we deduce that $ms=1$, so $1\in M$, which is a contradiction since $M$ is a maximal ideal. We then conclude that $P$ is a maximal ideal and we're done.